# Kafka Producer with multiple threads - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

I want to execute a Kafka producer using multiple threads. Below is the code that I have tried out. I am unaware of how to implement threads in Kafka producer since I am not well versed with Thread programming.
Below is the code for my producer.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Metric;
import org.apache.kafka.common.MetricName;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class KafkaProducerWithThread  {
    //init params
    final String bootstrapServer = "127.0.0.1:9092";
    final String topicName = "spark-data-topic";
    final String csvFileName = "unique_products.csv";
    final static int MAX_THREAD = 2;  //created number of threads

    //Logger
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducerWithThread.class);

    public KafkaProducerWithThread() throws FileNotFoundException {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new KafkaProducerWithThread().runProducer();
    }

    public void runProducer() throws IOException {

        //Read the CSV file from Resources folder as BufferedReader
        ClassLoader classLoader = new KafkaProducerWithThread().getClass().getClassLoader();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(classLoader.getResource(csvFileName).getFile()));

        //Create a Kafka Producer
        org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = createKafkaProducer();

        //Kafka Producer Metrics
        Metric requestTotalMetric = null;
        for (Map.Entry<MetricName, ? extends Metric> entry : producer.metrics().entrySet()) {
            if ("request-total".equals(entry.getKey().name())) {
                requestTotalMetric = entry.getValue();
            }
        }

        //Thread
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD);


        //Read the CSV file line by line
        String line = "";
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            i++;
            String key = "products_" + i;

            //Create a ProducerRecord
            ProducerRecord<String, String> csvProducerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key, line.trim());

            //Send the data - Asynchronously
            producer.send(csvProducerRecord, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                    //executes every time a record is sent successfully or an exception is thrown
                    if (e == null) {
                        //the record was sent successfully
//                        logger.info("Received new metadata. \n" +
//                                "Topic: " + recordMetadata.topic() + "\n" +
//                                "Partition: " + recordMetadata.partition() + "\n" +
//                                "Offset: " + recordMetadata.offset() + "\n" +
//                                "Timestamp: " + recordMetadata.timestamp());
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Error while producing", e);
                    }
                }
            });

            if (i % 1000 == 0){
                logger.info("Record #: " + i + " Request rate: " + requestTotalMetric.metricValue());
            }

        }

        //Adding a shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            logger.info("Stopping the Producer!");
            producer.flush();
            producer.close();
            logger.info("Stopped the Producer!");
        }));
    }

    public org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String> createKafkaProducer() {
        //Create Producer Properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "5");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true"); // For an idempotent producer
        //kafka can detect whether it's a duplicate data based on the producer request id.

        //Create high throughput Producer at the expense of latency & CPU
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "60");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, Integer.toString(32 * 1024)); //32KB batch size

        //Create Kafka Producer
        org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String> csvProducer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
        return csvProducer;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in implementing the threads in my Kafka producer program?
My Producer will be producing over a million records & so I want to implement threads for the same. I am aware of `ExecutorService` used for thread programming but I am not sure how to implement in this case.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are just copying lines from a CSV file into Kafka, then I am not convinced that multi-threading will help you. The Kafka producer is very high performance, bottleneck should be network I/O. And reading from a single file is also not something that you can easily parallelize.

Comment: There are probably also existing command-line tools that can do this for you.

Comment: KafkaProducer is thread-safe class. Producer has single IO thread per broker for better performance. Thus, I recommend to revise the design in favor of single KafkaProducer for the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- create a MessageSender class as given below.
- after creating the producer class, create a new MesssageSender object taking the producer record and producer as constructor args.
- invoke executorService.submit() to perform the task.

  ```
        class Producer {
           ExecutorService executorService = 
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD);
           //Read the CSV file line by line
           String line = "";
           int i = 0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
               //create produver record
               ProducerRecord<String, String> csvProducerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, key, line.trim());
               MessageSender sendMessage= new MessageSender(csvProducerRecord,producer);
              executorService.submit()...
            }
              }

          //Thread class          
          class MessageSender implements Runnable<>{
           MessageSender(Producerrecord,producer{
          //store in class level variable in thread class
          }
          public void run(){
              producer.send(csvProducerRecord...);
          }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet! Nice example along with the explanation! This is what I was looking for.